# How to refresh the list of files in a docker container after uploading images in nextjs?

Tags: docker, next.js, upload, multer, public

This code uploads an image to the backend of an app in next with multer.  It's saved in the public folder.  It works fine, but when I dockerize the app it doesn't update the list of files in the public folder, so I can't refresh the images.

It works fine with `npm run dev` or `npm run start` but it doesn't work in the docker container, however when I restart the docker container with docker restart, it renders all the images uploaded.

How can I refresh the list of files in the public folder?

```
input.onchange = async () => {
    const foto = input.files[0];
    const formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("image", foto);
    const respuesta = await fetch(/apis/fileupload/" + id, {
        method: "post",
        body: formdata,
        enctype: "multipart/form-data",
      });
    };
    input.click();
};
```

the images are rendered as:

```
<img src={id} alt='image'></img>
```